# grep and awk to copy only insert statements

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep

I have a .sql file that contains multi-lines Create, Insert, Alter Statements now I want to fetch only INSERT statements and copy that in another .sql file.

Sample for Create and Insert statements are

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."xyz"(
    "ID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "GID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "GDATA" BINARY(65536)
);


INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."INFORMIX_SERVERS" VALUES
(4521215141212121, 8763121524544545454
4545, X'3a000000127265706f7369746f7279536572');
```

I have tried the below commands with no success
cat dump.sql | grep -i 'INSERT* );'

`cat dump.sql | grep -E 'insert*);' | awk -F\> '{ print $2 }' | awk -F\< '{ print $1 }'`

Comment: kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw). Also are your insert statements always segregated with a paragraph or newline?

Comment: Surely thanks for the guidance, no it's not segregated. I have tried with some command like the below link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/945488/grep-a-line-which-start-and-end-with-a-pre-defined-character

but still, I am not able to get the output.

Comment: Sure, please do add these in your question(to avoid downvotes or close votes to your question), comments are not meant for efforts or codes adding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your Input_file's INSERT statements are having empty before and after its all lines then this could help.

```
awk -v RS= '/^INSERT/' Input_file
```

OR more generic solution you could try following.

```
awk '!NF||/^CREATE/{foundInsert=""} /^INSERT/{foundInsert=1} foundInsert' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF || /^CREATE/{   ##Checking condition if NF is NULL OR line starts from CREATE then do following.
  foundInsert=""    ##Nullifying foundInsert here.
}
/^INSERT/{          ##Checking condition if line starts from INSERT then do following.
  foundInsert=1     ##Setting foundInsert to 1 here.
}
foundInsert         ##Checking if foundInsert is SET then print that line.
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Shubhamkapoor, your welcome Shubham, Also request you again to add your efforts which you have posted/shown in your comments to your question as its encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance I have added my efforts and I will make sure from next time will add the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS=";" '/INSERT/ { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0);print $0";" }' file
```

Set the record separator to ";" and then search for records with INSERT. Strip the leading spaces with gsub and print.